# How can I use the subscribed message?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've written a very simple subscriber and now my task is to use the subscribed message as a "position value" for my servo. But how to do this ? Let's image that I would have a function called motor_position(uint16_t position) which I have to call and give it the new position value, when and where do I have to call the function?

So my question is, what is the simplest way to use the received message.

Thank you in advance

```
    #include "ros/ros.h"
    #include "message/message.h" //is a uint16_t var
    
    uint16_t a;
    
    void chatterCallback(const message::message::ConstPtr &msg)
    {
      a = msg->position;
      ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", a);
    
     
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topicname", 1000, chatterCallback);
    ros::spinOnce();
    
    // HOW CAN I CALL MY FUNCTION ?
    // motor_position(a); THIS is wrong for sure.  

    return 0;
    }
```

////////////////////////////EDIT////////////////////////////////
Does not compile ?!

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "message/message.h"


void chatterCallback(const message::message::ConstPtr &msg, int arg)
{
  //do something with arg
  uint16_t a = msg->position;
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", a);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int my_arg= 0;

ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topicname", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, my_arg ));
ros::spin();

return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77981/how-can-i-use-the-subscribed-message?/) by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-10**:
There is a standard ROS messages: std_msgs/UInt16 that you might wanna use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put it in the callback and that's it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-10**:
Thank you! This is what I was looking for, but can I also pass some parameters to the callback function from the main() like my filedescriptor for my port etc.  ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-10**:
Yes, check out boost::bind for this. You might also find some examples around here. - Although for your setup that might not be what you want. If you plan is to connect to a device, you should do that once in init and not on every message.

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-10**:
Thank you for your reply, I've tried myself and failed, the code doesn't compile (I edited my post see the new code).
I want just to pass my_arg to the callback function.